# Mock with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to isolate my angular unit specs.

My code base consists of a factory and a controller:

```
.factory('ServiceData', ->
    { message: 'im data from a factory service' }
)
.controller('Controller', ['$scope','ServiceData',($scope, ServiceData)->
    $scope.serviceData = ServiceData
```

And here is a spec for the controller:

```
it 'should get data from a service', ->
    spyOn(ServiceData, 'message').andReturn('im from a mock') # this doesn't work
    expect($scope.serviceData).toEqual 'im from a mock'
```

The spec doesn't work, because I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: ServiceData is not defined in ...controller_spec.js
```

I want to isolate my controller spec from my factory. How do I achieve this?

Also, this is a trivial example, but in future I will have very complex factories that get data from the server and all sorts. So I want to know how to stub them out.

I also might want to test how my controller behaves based on different things that are returned by the mocked out function, so I definitely want to use this approach.

I've tried to using `$provide`, but to much success

```
beforeEach ->
    module 'App', ($provide)->
        $provide.value 'serviceData', { message: 'im from a mock' }
```

results in:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
```

I mean...I just don't even know

Comment: I'd ditch the coffeescript, man

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

```
it 'should get data from a service', ->
    spyOn(ServiceData, 'message').andReturn('im from a mock') # this doesn't work
    expect($scope.serviceData).toEqual 'im from a mock'
```

The spec doesn't work, because I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: ServiceData is not defined in ...controller_spec.js

/quote

I think it should be something more like this:

```
it 'should get data from a service', -> //this is coffeescript syntax you're using I assume
    $scope.serviceData = ServiceData.serviceData
    expect($scope.serviceData).toEqual 'im from a service'
    //where ServiceData is defined as a service that returns a Plain Old Javascript Object
    //and that service returns an object in format: { serviceData: 'im from a service' }
```

If I understand what you are trying to test